# docker error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported

Tags: docker, centos

I am having problems to execute an older version of docker in a CentOS 7 VM. I installed docker `Docker version 17.09.1-ce` because its the version that I need, I need to run some software over it and the latest version `Docker version 17.12.1-ce` is not compatible with that, so I need to install and older version.

However, I installed docker as described in [docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-from-a-package) and it seems like it did it well, however when I go to run the hello world image I get:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

So, then I did:

```
dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

And then I get this error:

```
WARN[2018-03-04T19:32:51.374105228Z] [!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!] 
INFO[2018-03-04T19:32:51.404324386Z] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 14728 
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
ERRO[2018-03-04T19:32:52.452025257Z] [graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: driver not supported 
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

What is that? and what should I do in order to be able to execute the docker daemon but still with my installed docker version?

Comment: may I know how you solved this issue? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I type `dockerd` it was showing the error as

```
INFO[2019-12-03T01:39:44.030124494-05:00] Error while creating filesystem xfs on device docker-253:1-3117512-base: exit status 1  storage-driver=devicemapper
ERRO[2019-12-03T01:39:44.030161517-05:00] [graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper failed: exit status 1 
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: exit status 1
```

I changed the storage option to `ext4` using `dockerd --storage-opt dm.fs=ext4` and docker started successfully.

For more storage option use `man dockerd`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the graphdriver, but the error before that:

```
Error while creating filesystem xfs on device docker-253:1-3117512-base: exit status 1  storage-driver=devicemapper
```

It is probably a **kernel problem on your VM**.

**ON what host is your VM running?**

In case you are on a Xen host, you need to activate pygrub for the VM and install its own kernel inside the VM (instead of using the kernel of the host)

see: https://wiki.debian.org/PyGrub

1. inside the VM:

```
mkdir /boot/grub
apt-get install -y linux-image-amd64
cat > /boot/grub/menu.lst << EOF

default         0
timeout         2

title           Debian GNU/Linux
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /vmlinuz root=/dev/xvda2 ro
initrd          /initrd.img

title           Debian GNU/Linux (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /vmlinuz root=/dev/xvda2 ro single
initrd          /initrd.img

EOF
```

2. comment out

```
#kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-20-amd64'
#extra       = 'elevator=noop'
#ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-20-amd64'
```

and add:

```
bootloader = 'pygrub'
```

3. restart the VM

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to use docker-machine with a CentOS VM.  Turns out docker-machine copies over a file called 10-machine.conf to:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf
```

In this file dockerd is passed --storage-driver=overlay2.  When I removed this option, docker would start without issues.

To make a semi-permanent fix, I created a new file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/20-machine.conf
```

where I removed the --storage-driver=overlay2 option.  Docker-machine would then create properly the environment.

What is strange is that my docker engine was indeed using overlay2 if I ran docker info.

Answer (score 0):

This might not count as an answer because it's such a niche thing that it may have only been me experiencing this, but:

The issue for me was that I created a named pipe inside a single LXC container (using `mkfifo`). For some reason this stopped all other containers (and their docker instances) from being able to load the storage driver.

Once I deleted the pipe the docker instances were fine again.